# Como definir providers que funcionam apenas em ambiente local com Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

No Laravel 4, temos um arquivo chamado `app/config/app.php`, que usamos para poder definir informações de configuração que serão usadas na aplicação.

Quando estou em ambiente de desenvolvimento, eu configuro a aplicação para processar o `app/config/local/app.php`para poder ter informações que serão utilizadas apenas em ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Porém estou com um problema: Quando tento adicionar um valor em `providers` para ser processar apenas em ambiente local, estou recebendo erros ao rodar o `Artisan` ou memso a aplicação.

Eu imagino que isso esteja ocorrendo porque, quando armazenamos um arquivo de configuração, os índices de `app/config/app.php`são substituídos pelo que usamos em `app/config/local/app.php`, e provavelmente isso está fazendo com que algum item do índice `providers` seja removido.

Exemplo `app/config/app.php`:

```
'providers' => array(

    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
```

Exemplo `app/config/local/app.php`:

```
'providers' => array(
     'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider',
     'Xethron\MigrationsGenerator\MigrationsGeneratorServiceProvider',
 )
```

Como posso solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Laravel 4, há uma função chamada `append_config`, que reindexa um `array` para uma numeração alta, que começa do `99999`.

Isso acontece porque a classe `Config` por padrão sobescreve os `arrays` de mesmo índices presentes nos arquivos de configurações. Quando você define uma configuração local, o valor definido lá substitui o valor original.

Então, você poderia definir seu arquivo `app/config/local/app.php` da seguinte forma:

```
'providers' => append_config(array(
     'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider',
     'Xethron\MigrationsGenerator\MigrationsGeneratorServiceProvider',
 ))
```

Pra ser sincero, achei a solução do `append_config` um tanto quanto porca. Então, eu preferi resolver nomeando os índices:

```
'providers' => array(
     'local.generator.provider' => 'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider',
     'local.xethron.providers' => 'Xethron\MigrationsGenerator\MigrationsGeneratorServiceProvider',
 )
```

No caso acima, as nomeações não vão colidir, já que por padrão, o arquivo `app/config/app.php` usa um `array` sem índice (o que o torna sequencial e numérico).